# Finding height of ellipse from $r$ values

Tags: conic-sections

I have an ellipse. I know that $r_1 = 28$, $r_2 = 20$.

I'm trying to find the width and height of the ellipse. I know how to find the width of the ellipse with $r_1+r_2=2a$, but I can't figure out how to find the height of the ellipse.

How do I do this?

Comment: What are $r_1,r_2$ supposed to be here---the max/min distance from one focus?

Comment: They are the distances from each focus to a point on the ellipse.

Comment: I don't see how there's enough information to determine the minor axis. You can only give upper and lower bounds, I think.

Comment: I guess the lower bound is pretty trivial. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Assume without loss of generality that $r_1 \ge r_2 > 0$, and let the equation of the ellipse in standard form be $$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1, \quad a \ge b > 0.$$  Then the distance from the center to a focus is given by $c$ where $c^2 = a^2 - b^2$.  By the triangle inequality, we must have $r_2 + 2c \ge r_1$, which in turn implies $c \ge \frac{r_1 - r_2}{2}$.  Consequently,
$$b = \sqrt{a^2 - c^2} \le \sqrt{\left(\frac{r_1 + r_2}{2}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{r_1 - r_2}{2}\right)^2} = \sqrt{r_1 r_2}.$$  As such, for a general choice of $r_1, r_2$, there is an infinite family of ellipses satisfying the criteria.  In particular, for a chosen $b$ in the interval $(0, \sqrt{r_1, r_2})$, the points
$$(x,y) = \left(\pm \frac{r_1^2 - r_2^2}{4c}, \pm \frac{\sqrt{(2c-r_1-r_2)(2c-r_1+r_2)(2c+r_1-r_2)(2c+r_1+r_2)}}{4c} \right)$$ where again $c^2 = a^2 - b^2$, will satisfy the required distance criteria.

In your case, $r_1 = 28$, $r_2 = 20$ admits, for instance,
$$\{(a,b,c), (x,y)\} = \{(24,4\sqrt{35},4), (24,0)\}$$
which is easily verified, but
$$\{(a,b,c), (x,y)\} = \{(24,8,16\sqrt{2}), (3\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{62})\},$$
also works.  And here is an animation showing the family of ellipses and the point on the ellipse that satisfies the given criteria:

[image]

You can see that what is really happening here is that the locus of the intersection points of two circles with radii $r_1$ and $r_2$, as their centers move along the line passing through both centers, will necessarily be a point on the ellipse, so it is easy to see that the ellipse is not uniquely determined if only these distances are given, since the circles are free to move.

Comment: +1 for ‘Assume with loss of generality …’

Comment: @Aruralreader hahahaha thanks for catching that